# Angular, Maven like projects

Tags: angular6, angular-cli-v6

Is it possible to have multiple projects in a single angular application? 
For example, there's an application where Core ( layout, settings, etc), User, Orders are different modules. Here User module, will be displayed inside the layout which is defined in Core and so on.

Is it possible to build and deploy them separately like maven projects?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Angular6 comes with the ability to create library projects. Projects are grouped under projects property in the new angular.json configuration.

Using A6 CLI, 
`ng generate library <libraryName>`for each library project you want to create.
You could use `ng build --project <libraryName>` to build each of these library projects separately. You could either refer to these projects within your main application or you could publish these libraries to npm and import them in your main application.